# having a myriad of driver-related issues (graphics, internet, etc.)

Tags: wifi, drivers, graphic-drivers, nvidia, apt

i'm fairly new to Linux, so if there's any information i'm missing then please be patient with me!

for reference, here are my hardware specifications:
https://pastebin.com/RTV0WRVg

a fresh install of elementaryOS gives me the common bug of the display being tinted (in my case, my primary was green and secondary was red). after searching through support forums on Reddit and elsewhere, i determined that it may have been an issue with NVIDIA drivers. at this point, i was able to connect to wifi, so i attempted to both manually install NVIDIA drivers through terminal, as well as attempt the gnome-control-center solution. installation was EXTREMELY slow and continuously froze despite having run `sudo apt-get update`, so i ended up having to bin those ideas. i've test-driven multiple different distros and haven't had problems with apt-get like i have in eOS.

i then decided to run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to see if that could fetch the drivers i needed. this kept spitting an error that i was able to fix by following this guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1435715/sudo-ubuntu-drivers-autoinstall-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-version-ref

once installation seemed to be progressing, i left my computer for about an hour since installation was still slow (capping at 500kb/s), but it never froze and ended up completing successfully.

i restarted my computer and noticed that color was restored, however my resolution was locked at 1024x768, my second monitor was receiving no signal, and my wifi connection and settings vanished. a couple guides suggested i try to boot into an older version of the Linux kernal through GRUB, but that would land me in a version of eOS without a GUI.

i've only experienced issues like this with eOS despite having used multiple distros on the same hardware, so i'm at a complete loss. i do not have access to ethernet, so if it's possible to fix my installation offline or through a fresh install, that would be the best course of action.